# Part of proof of the set of continuous integrable functions is dense in $L^1(\Bbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to prove: If $g$ belongs to $L(\Bbb R, \Bbb B, \lambda)$ and $\epsilon\gt 0$, then there exists a continuous function $f$ such that $\Vert g-f\Vert_1=\int \lvert g-f\rvert \,\text{d}\lambda \lt \epsilon$.

I know this then implies the set of continuous integrable functions is dense in $L^1(\Bbb R)$
 in the metric $d(f,g)=\int_{\Bbb R}|f-g|\,\text{d}\mu$.
Note that $\Bbb B$ denotes the Borel set; $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue Measure on $\Bbb R$; $L^1$ denotes space of lebesgue integrable functions. I'm not sure if [Show that there exists a continuous function $f$ such that $\int |\chi_A-f| d\lambda\lt \epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751600/show-that-there-exists-a-continuous-function-f-such-that-int-chi-a-f-d-la) could help deducing the proof. Could someone show how to prove the above statement? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: approximate by simple functions and do use the other post.

Comment: Thanks, but could you show how to do this since I’m not sure how to approximate it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know from  [Show that there exists a continuous function $f$ such that $\int |\chi_A-f| d\lambda\lt \epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751600/show-that-there-exists-a-continuous-function-f-such-that-int-chi-a-f-d-la) that for every $\epsilon \gt0$ and every indicator function $\chi_A$ there exists a continuous function $f$ such that $$||\chi_A-f||_1\lt \varepsilon.$$

**Step 1:**
Assume $g$ is a simple function, i.e. it can be written as a linear combination of indicator functions:
$$ g = \sum_{i=1}^n \chi_{A_i} .$$
From the above result, we have that for each $i=1,\dots,n$ exists a continuous function $f_i$ with
$$||\chi_{A_i}-f_i||_1 \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{n}.$$
Thus, the function $f:=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i$ is continuous and we have
$$ || g - f ||_1 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n || \chi_{A_i} - f_i || < \varepsilon.$$
In short: For every simple function $g$ and every $\varepsilon >0$ exists a continous function $f$ with
$$ || g - f ||_1  < \varepsilon.$$

**Step 2:**
If $ g $ is integrable, then there exists a sequence of simple functions $g_n$ with $||g_n - g||_1 \to 0$.
From step 1 we have that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a continuous function $f_n$ exists with $|| f_n - g_n || < \frac{1}{n}$. Thus
$$ ||f_n -g ||_1 \leq ||f_n - g_n ||_1 + ||g_n -g ||_1 < \frac{1}{n} +  ||g_n -g ||_1 \to 0.$$

In short: For every integrable function $g$ and every $\varepsilon >0$ exists a continuous function $f$ with
$$ || g - f ||_1  < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: For step 2, following the sentence "Fix some $\epsilon \gt 0$", is it that "from step 1" we have that for any $n\in \Bbb N$ a continuous function $f_n$ exists with...

Comment: @user2901 no this is a different $\varepsilon$. I just took $\varepsilon =1$ now, maybe this is better to understand?

Comment: I’m not sure what’s the connection between step 1 and 2, do you combine these results to get the conclusion?

Comment: @user2901 In step 2 its used that **we have that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a continuous function $f_n$ exists with $||f_n - g_n|| < \frac{1}{n}$** which follows from step 1.

Comment: @user2901 just spotted a spelling mistake, should have been **from step 1 we have..* not **from step 2 we have**. I corrected it, maybe its clear now.